# Passing multiple commands to script calling time

Tags: bash, parameter-passing, timing

I have a bash script let's say foo.sh that in this minimal example looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
function __measure_time {
  time "$@"
}
__measure_time "$*"
```

What I want to do now is pass two commands to this script that are supposed to be run after another and I want to measure the time. So basically I am doing something like:

```
./foo.sh bash -c "echo 'ss' && sleep 1"
```

But that doesn't work the way I want it to. I don't get the 'ss' from the echo and the sleep is basically being ignored. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: For me this is working well.
The only edit I made to the command is prefix it with './'.
So it would be `./foo.sh bash -c "echo ss && sleep 1"`

Comment: Indeed, looks like the script I got is one line more complex than I thought. I completely overlooked that there is a function call before the time is called. It is not by me but I am trying to use it. Will add the code.

Comment: time is used to time the execution of a script and not a multitude of commands. That is, time won't accept more than one command as a parameter.

Comment: I am well aware that time only takes one argument. Therefor I am trying to trick it with the bash -c "..." construction. However it doesn't work when called throught the script described but perfectly fine when I am running it in a shell on it's own. I could of course just write the two commands in a script and invoke that with time but want to avoid having an extra file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the arguments to pass through correctly, you need to call `__measure_time` with `"$@"`, not `"$*"`:

```
#!/bin/bash
__measure_time() { #why the `function` syntax when you can be POSIX?
  time "$@"
}
__measure_time "$@"
```

`"$*"` joins all arguments on the first character of `$IFS` into a string.
`"$@"` is magic for "give me all the arguments, as if each was separately quoted."

Comment: Thanks. Is there any advantage to using $* as opposed to $@ that might justify not replacing it?

Comment: @FlyingTeller No